# Determining the homomorphism $\varphi: H \to \mathrm{Aut}(K)$ given a section $s: H \to G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

Per Wikipedia, a **split extension** is an extension $$1 \to K \overset{\beta}{\to} G \overset{\alpha}{\to} H \to 1$$ with a homomorphism $s: H \to G$ such that going from $H$ to $G$ by $s$ and then back to $H$ by the quotient map of the short exact sequence induces the identity map on $H$ i.e., $\alpha \circ s = \mathrm{id}_H$. This $s$ is called a section.

I often hear people saying that a section $s$ (upto conjugacy) immediately determines a semi-direct product $K \rtimes_{\varphi} H$ where $\varphi: H \to \mathrm{Aut}(K)$.

**Questions**:

1. How can we determine the homomorphism $\varphi$ given a specific section $s: H\to G$?

   **Edit**: I noticed Wikipedia provides the formula $\varphi_h(k) = \beta^{-1}(s(h)\beta(k)s(h^{-1}))$ but without any proof.
2. Does the semi-direct product $K \rtimes_{\varphi_h} H$ remain the same (upto group isomorphism) if I choose a different section $s'$ such that $s(h)$ and $s'(h)$ are conjugate elements in $G$ for all $h \in H$?

Comment: You are writing the semidirect product wrong; it’s $K\rtimes H$, not $H\rtimes K$. Think of the symbol $\rtimes$ as telling you which of the two subgroups is normal; in this case, $K$, not $H$. (Fixed now...)

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking in Question 2 - what exactly do you mean by "remain the same"? If you mean up to group isomorphism, then the answer is obviously yes, becuase they are both isomorphic to the original group $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt 1. Yes, I meant up to group isomorphism. 2. It's not obvious to me how both are isomorphic to the same group $G$. Could you write down a proof? Note that I'm considering outer semi-direct products here, so we're essentially constructing a group $G$ given a section $s: H\to G$. If I consider a different section $s'$ with the property that $s(h)$ is conjugate to $s'(h)$ for all $h \in H$, how would you prove that the resulting $G'$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: They are both isomorphic to the internal semidirect product of $\beta(K)$ by $s(H)$, both of which are equal to $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, but *why* are they both isomorphic to the internal semidirect product of $\beta()$ by $()$? It's not obvious to me, which is why I'm requesting for a proof. If you could write down the isomorphism map explicitly that'd be really helpful.

Comment: The isomorphism maps $(k,h)$ to $\beta(k)s(h) \in G$.

Comment: And if use the other section $s'$ then I think each $(k, h)$ is mapped to $(\beta(k), s'(h))$, right? Then we still have to show the map $(\beta(k), s(h)) \mapsto (\beta(k), s'(h))$ is an isomorphism. Moreover, it not only has to be set theoretically isomorphic but also isomorphic as groups. Not sure how to show that. If $s(h) = xs'(h)x^{-1}$ for all $h \in H$ that might be true, if $x$ is fixed for all $h \in H$, but that may not be the case.

Comment: As I said before they are both isomorphisms from semidirect products to the same group $G$. Since they are both ismorphic to $G$ they are clearly isomorphic to each other. This is really just the result that an internal semidirect product is isomorphic to a corresponding external semidirect product.

Comment: @DerekHolt "As I said before they are both isomorphisms from semidirect products to the same group $G$" --- Okay, this part is not clear to me. $(k, h)$ where $k \in K, h \in H$ getting mapped to $\beta(k)s(h)$ might produce a group $G_1$ while $(k, h)$ getting mapped to $\beta(k)s'(h)$ might produce a *different* group $G_2$. I don't see why $G_1 \cong G_2$.

Comment: $\beta$ is a map from $K$ to $G$ and $s$ and $s'$ are both maps from $H$ to $G$. The groups you are calling $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both equal to $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt As I said, $G$ doesn't exist a priori. We're using outer semi-direct products here. That is, we're *constructing* two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ using two different sections $s$ and $s'$. Saying that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are equal to $G$ if $G$ doesn't make sense if $G$ doesn't exist a priori.

Comment: $G$ was given as part of the statement of the problem. The maps $\beta$, $s$, and $s'$ were all defined with respect to a group $G$. The two outer semidirect were defined using maps $s:H \to G$ and $s':H \to G$. So without the group $G$ that you started with, you could not define them at all.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, I see. I still don't really feel convinced that $(k, h) \mapsto (\beta(k), s(h))$ is a group isomorphism but I will try to think more about it. Anyway, does this result hold even if $s(h)$ and $s'(h)$ are *not* conjugate elements in $G$ for all $h \in H$? Did you see the answer below btw (it seems to somewhat contradict you)?

Comment: @DerekHolt So are you basically saying: *no matter what* section $s$ we choose, the resulting semi-direct product will always be identical? That is, there can exist only one semi-direct product $H \rtimes K$ (upto isomorphism) given two groups $H$ and $K$, in all cases? That is weird, because I've seen two groups $H$ and $K$ having two or more possible split extensions.

Comment: Of course I am not saying that. In general,different maps $\varphi_h$ will give different semidirect products, which might or might not be isomorphic as groups. For example, if $|K|=3$ and $|H|=2$, then there are two isomorphic types of semidirect products, one is cyclic of order $6$, and the other is the nonabelian group of order $6$. But you seem to have forgotten the question you asked - read it again. You are starting with a group $G$, together with maps $\beta:K \to G$ and $\alpha:G \to H$, and then you are using section $s:H \to G$ to construct semidirect products ... ctd. below

Comment: In that situation, all of the semidirect products that you construct are isomorphic to the group $G$ that you started with. I wrote down the isomorphism $(h,k) \mapsto \beta(h)s(k)$ in a previous comment. Note that $\beta(h)s(k)$ is an element of the group $G$ that you started with, so this is an isomorphism between the semidirect product and $G$.

Answer (score 1):

It determines a semi-direct product on $K \rtimes_\varphi H$ (notice that $s(H)$ doesn't have to be normal) Here $\varphi$ takes an element $h\in H$ to conjugation by  $s(h)$ within G restricted to $\mathrm{Im}(K\rightarrow G)\cong K$.

For part 2, denote by $a_G(g)\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ conjugation by $g$. If we assume that there's a **single element** $h\in G$ s.t. $$s'(g)=(a_G(h)\circ s)(g)$$

Then this is true; what you are asking sounds untrue. In this case, you can notice that for any two conjugate elements:
$$g,a_G(h)(g)\in G$$

We have an isomorphism $F:K \rtimes_{\varphi} H \rightarrow K\rtimes_{\varphi_{s'}}H$ , $(x,y)\mapsto (x,a_G(h^{-1})(y))$.
This is obviously bijective, and it's a homomorphism (easy to check). 
I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you answer part 2 of the question too?

Comment: Why and how is conjugation by $s(h)$ restricted to $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$ btw? It's not clear to me why $s(h)\beta(k)s(h^{-1})$ should necessarily lie in $\mathrm{Im}(\beta)$. Could you please explain that part?

Comment: This is because the image of K is normal, as it is identical to the kernel of $\alpha$ and kernels are normal

Comment: Thanks. And does $s'(g)=(a_G(h)\circ s)(g)$ hold for all $g \in H$?

Comment: And what if the conjugating element $h \in G$ depends on the choice of $y \in H$? That is if it's not a fixed single element. Would it not be an isomorphism then? Why?

Comment: yes i assumed that it holds for all ∈  , otherwise I dont think this is true but im not sure how to find a counterexample without a lot of tedious work. please update if you find one.